# Prevent CPUCreditBalance Alarm from firing on ec2 instance launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using a `CPUCreditBalance` Cloudwatch alarm to alert me whenever `CPUCreditBalance` goes below a threshold **(e.g <50)**.

However, the problem is when instance is just launched it starts with base `credits (~20)` or `sometime even 0`.

***Is there a way I can prevent alarm from alerting when instance has just launched?***

**Update:** One possible solution that I can think of is writing a custom lambda function that checks if the instance has just started and suppress the alarms for such cases.

Comment: How quickly do you want to go into alarm? You could increase the alarm period and threshold to only enter into alarm after e.g. 15 minutes or however long it takes for your CPUCreditBalance to go up past 50

Comment: I am using t2.medium which takes around 2 hours to reach 50 if it starts from 0

Comment: Hint: You can [use math in CloudWatch metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) now. In the UI, create alarm, then "Select Metric", then in the Graphed Metrics tab you can "Add a math expression" which will use the other metrics you add to the graph as its METRICS() input. The "Select metric" button will be inactive as long as you have more than one metric checked in the list (displayed on graph). So to use the computed metric in the alarm let it be the only one displayed (checkbox checked), while the others are still listed.

Comment: Rate of change might be a useful metric there, but I don't know if they preserve the sign, i.e. if you can tell that the graph is going up or down. If they do, then you could alert under 50 only if credit balance has been decreasing.

Comment: @bgdnlp: Rate of change expression does preserve the sign. However, cloudwatch only allows selecting a single expression for setting alarm. I'd ideally want to trigger an alarm if (sign * balance < -50) where sign is either +1 or -1. I can't figure out how to extract just sign from the RATE expression

Comment: Assuming the rate will never go over 999, `FLOOR(RATE(m1)/1000)` will give you either -1 or 0. Which means `FLOOR(RATE(m1)/1000)*m1` will be either negative if the credits go down, or 0 otherwise. I think that's the solution to the question? Maybe I should turn it into an answer.

Comment: @bgdnlp: The formula seems to be correct. However, I need to use a condition with lower and upper bounds (-50 < val < 0), since val will be 0 if in case credits are increasing or constant. Cloudwatch only allows single bounds for the alarm conditions

Comment: Right. Again, I am not sure if this works, but something like `1/FLOOR(RATE(m1)/1000)*m1` and configure the alarm to treat missing data as good.

The point is that division by 0 results in an error, which doesn't show on the graph so hopefully it gets interpreted as missing data. In your case you should have the alarm trigger on value > -50, but then 0 would also trigger the alarm. By treating 0 as missing data, hopefully you can have your cake and eat it too. I'm really curious if this works.

Comment: From my tests it doesn't seem to be working. Oh well. I guess it's back to Lambda then. Have the alarm send notifications to an SNS topic and a Lambda function subscribed to that topic that will interpret the values. To keep it simple you can still use the FLOOR() formula and have Lambda check for (-50 < val < 0). If value is between -50 and 0, publish 1 to a custom metric, otherwise publish 0. Then set an alarm if that custom metric is > 0. Or just do everything in Lambda. Or set up a better monitoring system and get raw values from CloudWatch.

Comment: @bgdnlp: Thanks for all the help. Setting up lambda is currently not worth the investment for me. For now I am going ahead with setting alarm threshold to the initial credits (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-standard-mode.html). I'll ignore the occasional alerts in case instance launches with 0 initial credits.